# GAC'ing 4.0 assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, gac

I have built a dll with VS2010 targeted for framework 4.0. When I try to gac the assembly (either by drag drop the assembly into the GAC folder or by command line using gacutil), it does not give me any error. It says that the assembly was successfully added to the cache. But I am unable to see the assembly in the GAC folder. Wont it show up in GAC? Have they changed the GAC structure with VS2010?

The assembly is signed properly.

Comment: Why do you want to use the GAC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find GAC assembly list (.Net 4.0) on the following path :
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Check the following link for some details :
http://www.techbubbles.com/net-framework/gac-in-net-framework/

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

The GAC explorer plugin only shows .NET 3.5 assemblies. You can check the 4.0 GAC assembly list with gacutil.

Comment: I dont think they have given out a new version of gacutil for .NET 4.0. Have they?
See this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxgeneralprerelease/thread/b0591260-20a5-48af-99d5-55eca6e9e2e9

Comment: It's in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools".